# Permissions management in WPF application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures

I've developed an application in C# WPF in interaction with SQL Server 2012 Express. I have my stored procedures in my database. Every stored procedure performs some operation in application.

Now I'm trying to develop a module in my application where administrator could grant or revoke rights on the stored procedure execution for any user of the system. The administrator will select a user, a list of checkboxes will show up (it'll be the list of all the stored procedures just by operation name, not the procedure name), so that he can tick the required operations which will result on granting execution of the corresponding stored procedure for the user.

My question is that I wonder whether there is a standard approach to this? How can I match stored procedures to readable operation names?